# How many threads does ThreadPool data structure of multithreading python package create?

Tags: python, multithreading, threadpool

When I create a ThreadPool by determine the number of threads, I need to know if this number is the effective threads number that have been created and ran all together or this is just the limit and the effective threads number is actually determined by the length of the data provided.

```py
pool = ThreadPool(128) # does 128 threads are created after this line?
data = [1, 2, 3]
result = pool.map(func, data)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Comment: In case you're asking for `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool` ... yes, 128 threads are created in the first line during Pool initialization.

Comment: @Darkonaut thanks, is there any other way I can determine only its limit?

Comment: Not with `ThreadPool`. Note that because of the [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock), only one thread can execute Python bytecode instructions at a time. While multithreading in Python is **concurrent**, it's not **parallel**.

Comment: thanks a lot, found that I can use concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor instead for this feature